# upload product images in magento

Tags: magento, file-upload

I just installed magento on wampserver, and I can create categories and add products, but whenever I try to upload an image for a product, it seems that the "upload files" button doesn't work. Here is a [screenshot](http://i56.tinypic.com/712omu.png) .

Can anyone please help me out??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe update flash. This button uses Flash. Or check that the permissions are correctly set: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/magento_filesystem_permissions